# Play (Scala) auto-reload settings

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I am building a web application with Play 2.2 for Scala. I have one issue with the [auto-reload feature](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/PlayConsole):

I am adding some settings when running the server like this `play "run -Dtwitter.consumerSecret=mykey -Dtwitter.tokenSecret=mysecret"`. When the application re-compile on change, it does not take into account the parameters. I have to re-start the server. How to tell sbt to take into account the settings on reload.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: The 1 is built in, when CSS is changed and page is refreshed, the changes are immediately seen. Do you get any errors when running play run or at page reload? Also, try using a simple play run command with no additional parameters.

Comment: Hi Peter, I updated the question, actually you are right, it works perfectly fine for 1. The thing for 2 is I really need those parameters for my app to work and to display anything. I can't put those parameters in the code because they are sensitive (twitter key and secret)

Comment: Load from a `deploy.conf` that doesn't get committed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We add the following line to the bottom our `application.conf`

```
include "overrides.conf"
```

We make sure it's in the ignore file of our version control system.

The `overrides.conf` file allows us to tweak (and add) settings that should remain local.

Note that the `include` statement is ignored if the file can not be found.